# Manage PayPal Subscription Events with WooCommerce and Firebase

Tags: firebase, woocommerce, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-webhooks

I´m using WooCommerce with YITH Subscriptions Plugin to manage PayPal Subscriptions for a digital product. What´s the best practice to manage ..

1. Subscription renewed
2. Subscription expired

.. events?

**What I tried**

I tried the PayPal Webhooks to call a Firebase Function. For example: If a subscription expires I want to remove premium features from a user. It works well to call the firebase function which updates the specific entry. But for this I need the account eMail address or the uid from this user. Paypal gives me only the PayPal eMail address, which could be another one.

Do you have another idea to manage subscriptions in combination with PRO features?

This steps should all be automatic, of course:

- On subscription renew, WooCommerce should automatically create a new order to send the new invoice
- On expired subscription, WooCommerce or PayPal should automatically update a specific database entry to remove the PRO features.

What could I do? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Hope that you have found a solution. If not, you can try the filter hook from the `Integrate Firebase PRO` plugin. By using WooCommerce Hook, you can update data in Firebase.

https://firebase-wordpress-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/hooks/filters.html